# Regex to remove html tags while leaving PHP tags, and then remove empty lines

Tags: regex, newline

I am attempting to write a Regexp that I can use to convert a well formed HTML/php page into a plain-text/php replica. I have written the regexp to match the HTML tags while leaving the php:

```
<\w*[\s=\w-\d'"/!]*>
```

and I replace any matches with an empty string. The problem that I am having is that

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
```

becomes 7 blank lines. Is there a good way to replace the newline characters in these strings without replacing all newline characters in the whole document?

Comment: Which language are you using? You probably can't solve this with one regex. e.g. you'll need to handle stuff like: `<?php echo('<b title="remove this too?">boldstuff</b>') ?>`

Comment: I am actually using a tool called Regexr ( http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ ), and I am only using it for simple stuff. I could easily strip this stuff out by hand, I just thought the regexp would be a good learning experience.

Comment: `\s*<\/?\w*[^>]*>\s*` Seems to work using the above link.

Comment: Also, Since all of the HTML I am working with is my own and I don't particularly like embedding html in PHP echo statements (just a personal preference), my regex works well minus the newlines.

Comment: @Kassym: That removes all linebreaks and whitespace from around the tags, resulting in a single line of messy text.

Comment: Ahhh - learning regex... I salute you! Be sure to get in the habit of using the `'x'` free-spacing mode with lots of comments and indentation (check out a few of my answers here for some examples). If you are serious about learning regex, I _highly_ recommend reading: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!") - the time spent reading this will pay for itself _many_ times over. Also be sure to see: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got it. The trick is to strip any newline/whitespace characters BEFORE the html tags. Here's the working copy:

```
[\r\n\s]*?<\w*[\s=\w-\d'"/!]*>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how fail-proof this regex is, but on my test case it worked fine.

`(?<=\w)<[^?]\w*[^>]*>| *<[^?]\w*[^>]*>\s*` replace with nil string.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
```

=> `""`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hello</title>
    <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
```

=>

```
hello
hello
```

Comment: This also removes all php tags.

Comment: Should now not delete php tags. Do you have a test case that includes everything with desired output ?